# Gravar no banco de dados o horário de expediente e realizar uma consulta

Tags: php, mysql, time, script

Olá, estou procurando um Norte para criar com PHP e MySQL um jeito de gravar na base de dados o horário de funcionamento de vários estabelecimentos, para poder facilmente buscar e exibir se o estabelecimento está aberto, ou fechado, ou até que horas há expediente naquele dia.

Algo como o exemplo abaixo eu pretendo fazer, igual ao do Google Maps.

[image: Exemplo do resultado final pretendido]

Comment: Qual seria sua dúvida?

Comment: estou com dificuldade de bolar a parte onde vai ficar o horário de abertura e fechamento do estabelecimento, eu crio algo [ID - COD_EMPRESA - DIA_SEMANA - HORA_ABERTURA - HORA_FECHAMENTO ]?

Comment: Acho que ficaria melhor assim... `[ID - COD_EMPRESA - DIA_SEMANA - HORA_ABERTURA_MANHA - HORA_FECHAMENTO_MANHA - HORA_ABERTURA_TARDE - HORA_FECHAMENTO_TARDE ]`... Porque você tem 2 horários para cada dia da semana... Ou você pode fazer do jeito que você falou, so que criar uma outra coluna, por exemplo, `[Periodo]` e definir-la como manha(1) ou tarde(2), pra você conseguir diferenciar os 2 horários no mesmo dia da semana...

Comment: Boa, vou implementar algo assim, já que alguns locais tem horário diferenciado (trabalha a tarde e a noite) [ ID - COD_EMPRESA - DIA_SEMANA - HORA_ABERTURA - HORA_FECHAMENTO - PERIODO ]

Comment: pergunto? são muito registos (estabelecimentos) a incluir um horário?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode implementar essa funcionalidade da seguinte maneira:

## Estrutura do banco de dados

Para a estrutura da sua tabela do banco de dados, você pode criar algo assim:

```
[ID - COD_EMRPESA - DIA_SEMANA - HORA_ABERTURA - HORA_FECHAMENTO]
```

Desse modo, a empresa do exemplo na pergunta teria 11 registros no banco de dados: 2 para cada dia de segunda a sexta e 1 para o sábado.

Não acho que seja necessário determinar o período. Qual seria o período de uma empresa que fica aberta direto das 09:00 até às 18:00 por exemplo?

## Armazenando as informações no banco

Com base na documentação da função date() (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php), você armazenaria as informações de cada empresa no banco de dados da seguinte forma:

- os dias da semana (DIA_SEMANA) de 1 a 7 (sendo 1 segunda e 7 domingo).
- os horários de abertura/fechamento (HORA_ABERTURA e HORA_FECHAMENTO) como HH:MM (por exemplo 14:03 ou 17:10).

## Verificando horários de abertura e fechamento

Primeiro, para obter o dia da semana atual escreva:

```
$dia_da_semana = date('N')
```

E para obter a hora e minuto atuais:

```
$horario = date('H:i')
```

Então, basta comparar as strings retornadas acima com os valores presentes no banco de dados para determinar se a empresa está ou não aberta.