# Estrutura de dados para montar horário de funcionamento de lojas

Tags: mysql, estrutura-de-dados

Primeiramente, [encontrei essa dúvida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44452/gravar-no-banco-de-dados-o-hor%C3%A1rio-de-expediente-e-realizar-uma-consulta), que de fato é semelhante, porém não pareceu envolver alguns critérios que eu necessito, como o horário de funcionamento após a meia noite.

Estou desenvolvendo um app onde preciso mostrar o stauts de 'aberto/fechado' de uma loja. Esse horário é baseado na hora atual e no 'horário de funcionamento' que a própria empresa configura dentro do painel administrativo.

O problema para fazer isso funcionar, está ligado com a estrutura do banco de dados para armazenar esses dados, pois existem algumas variáveis. Por exemplo, digamos que seja um restaurante, e na quinta-feira ele tenha os seguintes horários de funcionamento: `10h-14h, 19h-02h`. Neste caso o horário após a meia noite, que ainda é referente ao período de quinta, deve ser jogado para o dia de sexta então a sexta feira teria um horário de funcionamento assim: `00h-02, 10h-14h, 19h-02h`.

Essa array de dados ainda precisa ser retornada para o `front` em `JSON` pois a base `front` é em `AngularJs`, além disso - para uma exibição correta, cada dia da semana só pode aparecer uma vez na array, para que não haja confusão por parte do usuário no momento da leitura.

Pois pode ficar estranho para o usuário 'ler' que o primeiro horário de sexta-feira é das 00h até 02h, sendo que na verdade este horário é referente à quinta-feira. Então, o modelo(apenas ideia) de como devo retornar os valores seria assim:

```
qui: 11 - 14, 19 - 23:59, (quebra de dia) 00 - 02
```

E não assim:

```
qui: 11 - 14
qui: 19 - 23:59,
sex: 00 - 02
```

No momento, tentei utilizar a seguinte estrutura de banco:

```
dia abre1   fecha1  abre2   fecha2
1   11:00   14:00   19:00   23:59
2    --:--   --:--   --:--   --:--
3    --:--   --:--   --:--   --:--
4   11:00   14:00   19:00   23:59
5   11:00   14:00   19:00   23:59
6   11:00   14:00   19:00   23:59
7   11:00   14:00   19:00   23:59
```

Essa estrutura é boa, mas tem a limitação de poder haver apenas 2 intervalos de funcionamento (ou 3, 4... mas ai seria necessário a inclusão de mais colunas).

A outra solução tentada foi essa:

```
loja_id    dia  abre    fecha
   1         1  11:00   14:00
   1         1  19:00   23:59
   1         1  00:00   02:00
   1         2  11:00   14:00
   1         2  19:00   23:59
   1         2  00:00   02:00
   1         3   --:--   --:--
```

Porém, o problema dessa estrutura é a geração do código final, em colocar todos os horários de segunda feira em uma mesma linha de resultado.

---

- Alguém sabe como aprimorar essa estrutura?
- Existe algum modo mais fácil? Ou um desses modelos que já utilizo o mais ideal?
- Alguma outra consideração a respeito?

Comment: [nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63338/13561) eu propus uma solução para um cronometro, que são gravados na base de dados tempos de inicio e fim, que pode ser adaptado para o seu problema.

Comment: Pois é, mas o problema maior está na parte do horário com a mudança de dia, no caso, da loja possuir um horário que ultrapasse a meia noite, mas ainda seja relacionado ao dia anterior.

Comment: no caso que falei, são usados *timestamps*, e você pode extrair somente o horário, de forma que é indiferente de passou da meia noite ou não, agora estou sem tempo para escrever uma resposta completa, mas pode ajudar

Comment: Sim sim, eu estou vendo ali a sua resposta e vejo se consigo adaptar algo, por que, se entendi sua orientação, o problema não é propriamente a manipulação da data como horário, é só a jogada dos dias mesmo. Mas verei a resposta com calma agora