# Estrutura tabela dia e horários (tipo agenda)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, table

Preciso criar uma tabela que contenha dias e horários de funcionamento de um estabelecimento, uma espécie de agenda. Essa tabela deve representar todos os dias da semana e em cada dia conter o horário de abertura e de fechamento. O desafio está sendo em criar esta tabela de forma que não tenha dados redundantes e que facilite a busca pelo horário de funcionamento de determinado dia.

Por exemplo, vou precisar buscar o dia de funcionamento do estabelecimento na próxima quarta-feira, ou o horário de hoje. Ainda existe um outro fator que são os dias de feriado (que o horário certamente será diferente dos dias normais, levando em conta que o estabelecimento esteja aberto). O Facebook tem algo parecido, nas páginas de empresas.

Na imagem uma representação da ideia (sendo que o primeiro horário é o de abertura e o segundo o de fechamento). Usarei MySQL.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como você vai usar isso? os horários sempre sermão fixos para os dias especificados ? seus campos serão de que tipo? string ? time ??

Comment: Teoricamente os horários serão fixos. Uma vez definidos, salvo alguma exceção, não serão mais alterados. Quanto aos campos, ainda não defini o tipo.

Comment: e como você vai mostra isso, da mesmo forma que esta em sua tabela acima? lado a lado os horários ?

Comment: Não. Na verdade eu vou filtrar os estabelecimentos "abertos" de acordo com o dia que o sistema for acessado. P.e.: segunda-feira, 19:20 horas, o usuário acessa o sistema e verá somente as empresas abertas naquele dia e horário. No caso do admin do estabelecimento/empresa, ele precisa ter uma visualização global dos dias e horários.

Comment: Então você tem uma relação direta empresa 1----> Muitos horários, se você criar campos com o TIPO varchar() para os horários você poderia criar sua tabela com os campos que você especificou acima adicionando a FK da   empresa  na tabela.

Comment: Veja se a resposta atende o que você precisa.

Comment: @GOKUSSJGod estou testando uma opção bem semelhante ao que me indicou, com algumas pequenas alterações. Assim que concluir dou meu feedback.

Comment: OK, veja que o banco de dados usado na resposta é sql server, mas a logica seria a mesma para seu banco. quando tive mais tempo monto alguma coisa no fiddle

Comment: @GOKUSSJGod, segui um pouco do que você sugeriu com o proposto nessa resposta (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44452/gravar-no-banco-de-dados-o-hor%C3%A1rio-de-expediente-e-realizar-uma-consulta?answertab=active#tab-top) - que são bem semelhantes, por sinal. Até agora está me atendendo bem.

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: @DaniloMiguel se consegui ajudar com a minha resposta, pode aceitar a resposta clicando no ✔ no lado esquerdo da mesma. Se necessitar de alguma mais ajuda avise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com comentários que você descreveu, você tem uma relação entre *EMPRESA* e *Horários* de *1 p/ Muitos*, dessa forma eu faria da seguinte forma.

```
declare @Empresa table
(
    id int,
    nome varchar(50)
)


declare @Horarios table
(
    id int,
    idEmpresa int,
    diaSemana varchar(20),
    abertura time,
    fechamento time
)

insert into @Empresa values
(1, 'X'),
(2, 'Y')

insert into @Horarios values
(1,1, 'segunda-feira', '08:00', '18:00'),
(2,1, 'terca-feira', '08:00', '18:00'),
(3,1, 'quarta-feira', '08:00', '18:00'),
(4,1, 'quinta-feira', '08:00', '18:00'),
(5,1, 'sexta-feira', '08:00', '18:00'),
(6,1, 'sabado', '09:00', '17:00'),
(7,1, 'domingo', '09:00', '15:00'),
(8,1, 'feriado', '10:00', '13:00'),
(9,2, 'segunda-feira', '08:00', '18:00'),
(10,2, 'terca-feira', '08:00', '18:00'),
(11,2, 'quarta-feira', '08:00', '18:00'),
(12,2, 'quinta-feira', '08:00', '18:00'),
(13,2, 'sexta-feira', '08:00', '18:00'),
(14,2, 'sabado', '08:00', '18:00'),
(15,2, 'domingo', '09:00', '17:00'),
(16,2, 'feriado', '09:00', '16:00')

declare @horaInformada time = '10:00';

select nome, diaSemana, abertura, fechamento
from @Empresa e
join @Horarios h
on h.idEmpresa = e.id
where e.id = 2
and diaSemana = 'feriado'
and @horaInformada between abertura and fechamento
```

Mais já deixo claro que pode haver varias respostas contraditórias a essa, porque sua pergunta eu classificaria como **(principalmente baseada em opiniões)**... cada um pode especificar uma forma diferente de fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma seria:

```
id_dia(Primary key) -> int
horario -> varchar(15)
```

Em id_dia você coloca o número do dia da semana correspondente, e no horario o horario de funcionamento.
O id_dia deve ser o numero que corresponde ao dia da semana, exemplo:

> Id_dia
>
> (1) para domingo
>
> (2) para segunda
>
> (3) para terça
>
> ...
>
> (7) para sabado

Answer (score -2):

Aconselho a fazer três tabelas:

A primeira tabela será para inserir os dias da semana, para isso crias dois campos:

```
semana -> Nome Tabela
s_id   -> int
s_name -> varchar
```

A segunda tabela será para inserir os horários de abertura e fecho, para isso crias 4 campos:

```
horarios   -> Nome Tabela
h_id       -> int
h_s_id     -> int
h_abertura -> time
h_fecho    -> time
```

A terceira tabela será para inserir os feriados, para isso crias 5 campos:

```
feriados     -> Nome Tabela
f_id         -> int
f_s_id       -> int
f_diaferiado -> datetime
f_abertura   -> time
f_fecho      -> time
```

Depois para retornares os valores de um dia especifico basta usares um `join`, exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM semana 
LEFT JOIN horarios ON horarios.h_s_id=semana.s_id
WHERE s_name=domingo
```